# i want to call function inside directive from controller where directive is included in html file which load when ng-if is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```js
   var app = angular.module('jkuri.gallery', []);  
app.controller("userProfile", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$resource', 'fullname', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, $location, $resource, fullname, $timeout){
    $scope.openAlbum = function(){
      $scope.showInject2 = true;
    };

   $scope.closeAlbum = function(){
     $scope.showInject2 = false;
    console.log("hover");
   };
   $scope.dataUri = function(){

    //console.log('Res image', $scope.resImageDataURI);
    //console.log($scope.resBlob);
    console.log($scope.urlBlob);
    //$scope.file = new File($scope.urlBlob, "name");
    //console.log($scope.file);
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.cropOne = false;
    $scope.sendRequest($scope.urlBlob, $scope.id, $scope.description, $scope.photoTag);
   }
   }]);


  app.directive('ngGallery', ['$document', '$timeout', '$q', '$templateCache', '$location',function($document, $timeout, $q, $templateCache, $location) {
'use strict';

return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
        images: '=',
        thumbsNum: '@',
        sendRequest: '='
    },
    templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {
            return attrs.templateUrl || defaults.templateUrl;
        },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        setScopeValues(scope, attrs);



        scope.images = [
            {"id":"84","img":"images/image2.jpg","thumb":"images/image2.jpg"},
            {"id":"85","img":"images/image2.jpg","thumb":"images/image2.jpg"},
            {"id":"86","img":"images/image2.jpg","thumb":"images/image2.jpg"},
            {"id":"87","img":"images/image2.jpg","thumb":"images/image2.jpg"},
            {"id":"89","img":"images/image2.jpg","thumb":"images/image2.jpg"}
        ];

        scope.sendRequest = function(imgBlob, id, imgDescription, imgTag){
            console.log(imgBlob);
            console.log(id);
            console.log(imgDescription);
            console.log(imgTag);
            //scope.images.push({"id":id,"img":imgBlob,"thumb":imgBlob, "description":imgDescription});
            scope.images.push({"id":"89","img":"images/image3.jpg","thumb":"images/image3.jpg"});
            $timeout(function() {
                var calculatedWidth = calculateThumbsWidth();
                $thumbnails.css({ width: calculatedWidth.width + 'px' });
            },100);
        };



    }
};

}]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="jkuri.gallery" ng-controller="userProfile" class="cropppe">
  <!-- <div class="cropped-one"><img ng-src="{{resImageDataURI}}" /></div> -->
 <div class="cropped-one"><img ng-src="{{urlBlob}}"/></div>
    <div class="float-right-btns">
          <textarea name="" rows="" cols="" placeholder="Give a description"></textarea>
           <a onclick='show();'>Cancel</a>
           <a class="mfp-close" ng-click="dataUri()" style="background:#448ccb;color:#fff;">Upload</a>
     </div>
    </div>

<div ng-if="showInject2" style="position:absolute;" ng-gallery images="images" thumbs-num="11" send-request="sendRequest">
</div>

<div class="ng-gallery">
    <div class="ng-scope">
        <img class="ng-thumb" src="image1.jpg" ng-click="openAlbum()" ng-mouseover="closeAlbum()">
    <div class="link-album"><p><strong>View</strong> or <strong>Add/Change</strong><br>Pictures</p></div>
</div>
```

I have a page in which directive is called when ng-if is true normally directive function is calling when i put directive in the page...and when ng-if gets true...after that function from controller is not calling function which is inside directive.

Exactly problem i am facing is that sendRequest function isn't calling from controller of directive and if i put that directive without ng-if it works like a charm...

> Error: $scope.sendRequest is not a function

Comment: Maybe this will be of assistance? https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3225

Comment: I think the problem is how to call function which is in directive also it becomes childCtrl...

Answer (score 0):

I have just simply added $parent in the function

```
<div ng-if="showInject2" style="position:absolute;" ng-gallery images="images" thumbs-num="11" send-request="$parent.sendRequest">
```